# Facing issue to connect to SQLLITE table using raw sql

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to connect to SQLite table using a raw sql query but unsuccessfully.

Here is my model:

```
class CsqAgentReport(models.Model):
    nodeid_sessionid_sequenceno = models.TextField(db_column='NodeID-SessionID-SequenceNo', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    callstarttime = models.TextField(db_column='CallStartTime', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    callendtime = models.TextField(db_column='CallEndTime', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    contactdisposition = models.IntegerField(db_column='ContactDisposition', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    originatordn_callingnumber_field = models.IntegerField(db_column='OriginatorDN(CallingNumber)', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    destinationdn = models.IntegerField(db_column='DestinationDN', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    callednumber = models.IntegerField(db_column='CalledNumber', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pivotoriginatordn = models.TextField(db_column='PivotOriginatorDN', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pivotcallednumber = models.TextField(db_column='PivotCalledNumber', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    csqnames = models.TextField(db_column='CSQNames', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    queuetime = models.TextField(db_column='QueueTime', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    agentname = models.TextField(db_column='AgentName', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ringtime = models.TextField(db_column='RingTime', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    talktime = models.TextField(db_column='TalkTime', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    worktime = models.TextField(db_column='WorkTime', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    nomcsq = models.TextField(db_column='NomCSQ', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    idunique = models.IntegerField(db_column='IDUnique', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    originatordnhandeled = models.IntegerField(db_column='OriginatorDNHANDELED', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    originatordnnothandeled = models.IntegerField(db_column='OriginatorDNNOTHANDELED', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    outboundmissedcall = models.TextField(db_column='OutboundMISSEDcall', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    missedcallshandeledy_n = models.IntegerField(db_column='MISSEDCALLSHANDELEDY-N', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'CSQ Agent Report'
```

Here is the view I created:

```
def csq_detail_view(request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT  * FROM 'CsqAgentReport'")
        obj = cursor.fetchone()
    context = {
                'object': obj
              }
    return render(request,"CSQ/detail.html",{context})
```

and here is the html:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    <ul>
    {% for var_nbr_app_repond in object %}
        <li> {{var_nbr_app_repond}} </li>
    {% endfor %}
    
    {% endblock %}
```

The error message is the following :

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/CSQ_Detail/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: CsqAgentReport.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no such table: CsqAgentReport.

the error is self explanatory, did you create the database ? is there `sqlite3` file in your project root folder ?

run those commands :

```
(venv) python manage.py makemigrations
```

to create a migration for your model, and

```
(venv) python manage.py migrate
```

to create associated table in your database.

## Update

you've made a mistake, refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#db-table on how to rename/override table name using `db_table` in `Meta` class. it should be:

```
class CsqAgentReport(models.Model):

[..]

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'csq_agent_report'  # HERE snake lower-cased strings
```

## Update 2

- since you've renamed `db_table` to `csq_agent_report` instead the default one `CsqAgentReport` you should update the sql statement to

```
cursor.execute("SELECT  * FROM 'csq_agent_report'")
```

- in return statement you don't need to wrap `context` in dictionary `{..}` because it's already.

change those 2 lines:

```
def csq_detail_view(request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT  * FROM 'CsqAgentReport'")  # HERE
        obj = cursor.fetchone()
    context = {
                'object': obj
              }
    return render(request,"CSQ/detail.html",{context})  # HERE
```

to

```
def csq_detail_view(request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT  * FROM 'csq_agent_report'")  # HERE
        obj = cursor.fetchone()
    context = {
                'object': obj
              }
    return render(request,"CSQ/detail.html", context)  # HERE
```

## Update 3

you have to change `managed` to `True` instead `Flase`

refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#managed

```
class CsqAgentReport(models.Model):

[..]

    class Meta:
        managed = True  # Here
        db_table = 'csq_agent_report'  # HERE snake lowercased strings
```

and don't forget to rerun migration commands.

Comment: Hello , Yes the database is already created and i confirm that there  is a sqlite3 file named "db.sqlite3"in the project folder . I have run the commands that you provided and the system returned the following : F:\1AtnStatUccx\StatUccx>python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

F:\1AtnStatUccx\StatUccx>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: CsqAgentReport, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply. The issue still persists

Comment: maybe you need to backup the OLD `sqlite`.` file and rerun migrations commands so the NEW `db_table` name of table can be taken in concideration, try this and let me know

Comment: I did a bkp of the DB table and performed migrations command again , unfortunatly i ended with the same issue .

Comment: @walid i've made an other update it's about `context` you don't need to enclose it between `{ .. }`

Comment: @walid check agin my update it should now be solved , i hope so

Comment: I did the update as per your recommendation in db_table of the models.py , and i aso updated the views querry with correct dbname but still facinf the same issue : Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/CSQ_Detail/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value: 
no such table: csq_agent_report

Comment: run this command `sqlite3 db.sqlite3` then in the prompt run `sqlite> .tables` to show all tables

Comment: @walid have a look at my 3rd update if doesn't work try to comment that line

Comment: Now it is working as i have no error message but the web page doesn't display any data except the title